# Underlining Entire Sections Regardless of Text

Tags: html, css, underline

I need to replicate an old work form line for line with Django.

Some of the fields need to be underlined whether or not there is text.

For a visualization see the "above employee's skill and knowledge have been objectively evaluated..." field [found here](https://www.firedrive.com/file/ABFFFF1E24068D7D).

How would I add {{ data }} in the underlined section? Another complication that arises here is that it needs to wrap to a new line every time it reaches the end of a line.

My best guess is that a table with a bottom-border could somehow be used, but that would make it very difficult to wrap the paragraph at the end of lines.

My question was originally a bit vague so here is a simpler explanation.
I need a section that ALWAYS has exactly 6 lines, all of it underlined, and {{ data }} can be inserted. This also needs to be word-wrap friendly.

I found a way to accomplish this. It's a bit of an ugly solution but I parsed {{ data }} and added a dynamic amount of underlined spaces based on data's length.

Comment: are you limited to using css, or are you open to using jquery too ? (Alternatively, see if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/microbians/csYjC/)

Comment: I'm definitely open to jQuery too. Nothing was underlined in your jsfiddle though.

Comment: It was not my fiddle.. Just found that if you were looking for a CSS only solution.

Comment: What are your browser support requirements for this?

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure, but, you could use a background to draw dots and lay over it a contenteditable span . **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/cugwH)**

---

HTML & CSS

```css
form {
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}

label,
span,
legend {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
}

p {
  min-height: 6em;
  /* tune for number of empty lines to show */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 95%, black 95%) 0 -0.2em white;
  background-size: 0.25em 1.2em;
}

span[contenteditable]:empty:before {
  /* role="placeholder" */
  content: "Tell us all about It ! (5 lines or more)";
  /* your own text of course */
  font-style: italic;
  color: gray;
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -100%;
  /* keeps dot being seen underneath, avoids span background being drawn */
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Fill in Form</legend>
    <p>
      <label>What do you expect ?</label>
      <span contenteditable="true"></span>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Do not forget that span is not an input nor a textarea, You need a javascript support to generate this span and bind it to a textarea

Comment: I actually did try going the background line route. Unfortunately the PDF renderer I'm using isn't compatible with background images. I found a sort of hackish way to do it by appending a dynamic amount of spaces to the string. I'm going to award you the bounty because your answer was the best potential solution.

Comment: So funny story. I ended up coming back to this solution. It needed to be done using the @page css decorator but it ended up working out :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfect but it works - you may want to fiddle with this a bit to get exact values:

```
.text
{
    line-height: 2.0em;
    height: 12.0em;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
        180deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 1.95em,
        rgb(100,100,100) 2.0em
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly - Just wrap the {{ data }} in divs with vertical-align in the middle and add a bottom border and some padding. Wrap it all in a container with a line height. I whipped up a fiddle to illustrate.

```
.middle {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px 5px 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PkBb5/2/

Comment: I understand how to underline a section. I need a section that ALWAYS has exactly 6 lines, all of it's underlined, and {{ data }} can be inserted into it.